# .htaccess multiple rewrite rules on multiple php files not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new on .htaccess and rewrite rules. So if my question is not relevant, please forgive me.

I have below Rewrite rule;

`RewriteRule ^\yazarlar$ /writer-list.php [L]`

I'm trying to achieve if someone hit url `http://example.com/yazarlar` or `http://example.com/yazarlar/` they should see `http://example.com/writer-list.php` file. But it's not working.

Am i missing something?

### FULL .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^haber/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ article.php?link=$1&i=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]?)?$ /article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ /article-list.php?link=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^\yazarlar$ /writer-list.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to escape the `\y` and remove redundant rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^yazarlar/?$ writer-list.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^haber/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ article.php?link=$1&i=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article-list.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```